# What hook is most appropriate for code that should run as early as possible in bootstrapping but only on certain paths?

Tags: redirection, hooks

I am writing a module that should run code as early as possible because it's a conditional redirect to another page, so the first page doesn't need to finish loading.

I only want to run it on `/foo/*`.

Is there a hook that can be bound to a particular path, like `hook_form_alter()` can be with form IDs? Or should I just use `hook_init()`?

Comment: is `foo` an alias or an internal path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the forms, there's [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), but that happens near the end, making it a bad place for redirects.

[`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) should be fine, but is not invoked on cached pages.

[`hook_boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) sounds self-explaining; it's run so early that you can't call any module's function, not even drupal's.

however, since you need a conditional redirect and you already have your own module, just add it atop the page callback of 'foo/*'.

if that callback it's not defined in your module, use [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to have that path pointing to a custom function that will execute your conditional redirect.

Comment: Interesting. Will `hook_boot()` run on cached pages as well?

Comment: Yes, every page, always.